# Find by Object Attributes in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

i was wondering whether it is possible to find an object using an example object like you can in hibernate with:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.Sex = 'F';
cat.Color = Color.Black;
List results = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat)).Add( Example.Create(cat)).List();
```

I know i can find by primary key, just not looking forward to writing a million lines of findByX, findByY etc etc.

thanks.

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so since it's not available in the current JPA API, the only way i can see how to implement it would be by using this:

```
 public <T> List<T> findByAttribute(T object) {
    List<T> found = new ArrayList<T>();
    Map m = null;
    try {
        m = BeanUtils.describe(object);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }

    String query = "select c from " + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + " c  where ";
    if (m != null) {
        for (Object key : m.keySet()) {
            if (!key.equals("class")) {
                Object value = m.get(key);

                if (value != null) {
                    try {
                        ConvertUtils.convert(m.get(key), PropertyUtils.getPropertyType(object, key.toString()));
                        query += " c." + key + " = :" + key + " and";

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        // the reason for this noncy try catch is so that you don't add parameters that are not primitives
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        query = query.substring(0, query.lastIndexOf("and"));
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
        for (Object key : m.keySet()) {
            if (!key.equals("class")) {
                if (m.get(key) != null) {
                    try {
                        Object o = ConvertUtils.convert(m.get(key), PropertyUtils.getPropertyType(object, key.toString()));
                        q.setParameter(key.toString(), o);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("what we have here is a failure to communicate");
                        System.out.println("only primitive types allowed");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        List resultList = q.getResultList();
        if (resultList != null) {
            found.addAll(resultList);
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

but this will only work for primitive types i think. I guess it's something.

Thanks anyway

N

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if the Criteria API is being considered for the next JPA release. There is some discussion about it  [here](http://relation.to/Bloggers/ATypesafeCriteriaQueryAPIForJPA).

It would seem that at the moment if you want the Query by Example and Criteria features then you will have to use Hibernate.